# Python Segmentation Fault when running via ssh

Tags: python, ssh, segmentation-fault, multiprocessing

When I run my multi-processing python program from terminal (command line), all works fine.

```
$ /home/florian/tests/run_tests.sh -d -w
```

Script `run_tests.sh` is just a wrapper for Python call (sets variables and calls python)

When **exactly the same** command I run from another box **using SSH**, almost all tasks (processes) fail with 'segmentation fault' (165 of 189 [87%]):

```
$ ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no florian@remote '/home/florian/tests/run_tests.sh -d -w'
```

Environment:

```
OS: SLES11
Python: 3.8.1
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(2)-release (x86_64-suse-linux-gnu)

Number of CPUs: 24


core file size          (blocks, -c) 1
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 1029396
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) 112008408
open files                      (-n) 32768
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 32768
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 1029396
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) 108780880
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

I even tried to limit **number of CPUs used to 1** - still not working

```
import multiprocessing as mp

#pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())
pool = mp.Pool(1)
```

- Do you have any idea why it behaves like that: works on local, fails on ssh?
- Do you know any SSH settings that could help in memory allocation (if this is an issue)?

Thanks in advance,
Zbigniew

Answer (score 0):

To anyone that would face similar issue: problem was in **environment variables**.

When connecting via SSH, only some variables remain - rest is wiped out (see details in ssh description).

So inside wrapper script I had to `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH` - thanks to my colleague **Francois** for very valuable hint :)

Silly mistake, but... maybe someone benefits of this answer.